# How to update the record by adding one more child row for exciting child by using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Here I am going to update the record. By adding one more child for the exciting parent and here I am removing the child by iterating the child's and then I am updating the record but its giving the exception as. 
**EXCEPTION:org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: com.treamis.entity.LibraryBookListEntity.chield**

Here is my code.

```
LibraryBookForm lb = (LibraryBookForm) form;
        int bookid = lb.getBooklistid();
        System.out.println("bookidbookidbookid" + bookid);
        String[] bar = lb.getBarcode();
        String[] accission = lb.getAccessno();
        System.out.println("accissionaccission" + bar);
        UserEntity msg;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        msg = (UserEntity) session.getAttribute("user");
        int catid = lb.getCategory();
        Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        String d1 = lb.getBilldate();
        java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(d1);
        java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(temp.getTime());
        String d2 = lb.getDateAdded();
        java.util.Date temp1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(d2);
        java.sql.Date submissionDate = new java.sql.Date(temp1.getTime());
        CategoryEntity ce = (CategoryEntity) ses.get(CategoryEntity.class, catid);
        LibraryBookListEntity lbl = (LibraryBookListEntity) ses.load(LibraryBookListEntity.class, bookid);

        Set<LibraryBarCodeEntity> s1 = lbl.getChield();
        for (LibraryBarCodeEntity lbb : s1) {
            System.out.println("inside delte");
            ses.delete(lbb);
        }

        Transaction tx = ses.beginTransaction();
        lbl.setEdition(lb.getEdition());
        lbl.setPublisher(lb.getPublisher());
        lbl.setPlace(lb.getPlace());
        lbl.setPage(lb.getPag());
        lbl.setSource(lb.getSource());
        lbl.setBillno(lb.getBillno());
        lbl.setBilldate(date);
        lbl.setPublishedyear(lb.getPublishedyear());
        lbl.setCallno(lb.getCallno());
        lbl.setIsbn(lb.getIsbn());
        lbl.setBooktitle(lb.getBooktitle());
        lbl.setRack(lb.getRack());
        lbl.setAuthor(lb.getAuthor());
        lbl.setPrice(lb.getPrice());
        lbl.setCategoryid(ce);
        lbl.setDateAdded(submissionDate);
        lbl.setTcopies(lb.getTcopies());
        lbl.setAddedBy(msg);
        lbl.setAddedate(new Date());
        lbl.setModifiedBy(null);
        lbl.setModifiedDate(null);
        try {
            java.util.List list = Arrays.asList(bar);
            Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(PageSize.A4));
            File file = new File("d://" + lb.getBooktitle() + ".pdf");
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file, false));
            document.open();
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            Set<LibraryBarCodeEntity> s = new HashSet<LibraryBarCodeEntity>();
            LibraryBarCodeEntity mb = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("inside library model edit");
                mb = new LibraryBarCodeEntity();
                System.out.println("bar[i]" + bar[i]);
                System.out.println("bar[i]" + accission[i]);
                mb.setBarCode(bar[i]);
                mb.setAccessno(accission[i]);
                mb.setParent(lbl);
                para.add(new Phrase(new Chunk(BarcodeDao.genarateBarcode(bar[i], writer), 0, 0, true)));
                para.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));
                para.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));
//                s.add(mb);
                ses.saveOrUpdate(lbl);
            }
//            lbl.setChield(s);
            tx.commit();
```

Here is my LibraryBookListEntity  Entity

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.treamis.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "LibraryBookListTable")
public class LibraryBookListEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "BookListId")
    private int booklistid;
    @Column(name = "ISBN", nullable = false)
    private String isbn;
    @Column(name = "edition", nullable = false)
    private String edition;
    @Column(name = "publisher", nullable = false)
    private String publisher;
    @Column(name = "place", nullable = false)
    private String place;
    @Column(name = "page", nullable = false)
    private String page;
    @Column(name = "source", nullable = false)
    private String source;
    @Column(name = "billno", nullable = false)
    private String billno;
    @Column(name = "callno", nullable = false)
    private String callno;
    @Column(name = "BookTitle", nullable = false)
    private String booktitle;
    @Column(name = "BookAuthor", nullable = false)
    private String author;
    @Column(name = "BookPrice", nullable = false)
    private float price;
    @Column(name = "RackNumber", nullable = false)
    private String rack;
    @Column(name = "PublishedYear", nullable = false)
    private String publishedyear;
    @Column(name = "NoofCopies", nullable = false)
    private int tcopies;
    @Column(name = "DateAdded", nullable = false)
    private java.sql.Date dateAdded;
    @Column(name = "billdate", nullable = false)
    private java.sql.Date billdate;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = CategoryEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_Id", referencedColumnName = "category_Id", nullable = true)
    private CategoryEntity categoryid;
    @OneToOne
    private UserEntity addedBy;
    @OneToOne
    private UserEntity modifiedBy;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
    @JoinColumn(name = "BookListId", referencedColumnName = "BookListId")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    private Set< LibraryBarCodeEntity> chield;

    public Set<LibraryBarCodeEntity> getChield() {
        return chield;
    }

    public void setChield(Set<LibraryBarCodeEntity> chield) {
        this.chield = chield;
    }
    //@Column(name = "AddedDate", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date addedate;
    // @Column(name = "ModifiedDate", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date modifiedDate;

    public int getBooklistid() {
        return booklistid;
    }

    public void setBooklistid(int booklistid) {
        this.booklistid = booklistid;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public String getBooktitle() {
        return booktitle;
    }

    public void setBooktitle(String booktitle) {
        this.booktitle = booktitle;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getRack() {
        return rack;
    }

    public void setRack(String rack) {
        this.rack = rack;
    }

    public int getTcopies() {
        return tcopies;
    }

    public void setTcopies(int tcopies) {
        this.tcopies = tcopies;
    }

    public java.sql.Date getDateAdded() {
        return dateAdded;
    }

    public void setDateAdded(java.sql.Date dateAdded) {
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }

    public CategoryEntity getCategoryid() {
        return categoryid;
    }

    public void setCategoryid(CategoryEntity categoryid) {
        this.categoryid = categoryid;
    }

    public UserEntity getAddedBy() {
        return addedBy;
    }

    public void setAddedBy(UserEntity addedBy) {
        this.addedBy = addedBy;
    }

    public UserEntity getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(UserEntity modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    public java.util.Date getAddedate() {
        return addedate;
    }

    public void setAddedate(java.util.Date addedate) {
        this.addedate = addedate;
    }

    public java.util.Date getModifiedDate() {
        return modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(java.util.Date modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

//    public String getAccessionnumber() {
//        return accessionnumber;
//    }
//
//    public void setAccessionnumber(String accessionnumber) {
//        this.accessionnumber = accessionnumber;
//    }
    public String getEdition() {
        return edition;
    }

    public void setEdition(String edition) {
        this.edition = edition;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public String getBillno() {
        return billno;
    }

    public void setBillno(String billno) {
        this.billno = billno;
    }

    public String getCallno() {
        return callno;
    }

    public void setCallno(String callno) {
        this.callno = callno;
    }

    public java.sql.Date getBilldate() {
        return billdate;
    }

    public void setBilldate(java.sql.Date billdate) {
        this.billdate = billdate;
    }

    public String getPublishedyear() {
        return publishedyear;
    }

    public void setPublishedyear(String publishedyear) {
        this.publishedyear = publishedyear;
    }
//    public Set< LibraryBarCodeEntity> getChield() {
//        return chield;
//    }
//
//    public void setChield(Set< LibraryBarCodeEntity> chield) {
//        this.chield = chield;
//    }
}
```

Here is my another entity

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.treamis.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "LibraryBarCodeTable")
public class LibraryBarCodeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "S_no", nullable = false)
    private int S_no;
    @Column(name = "BookBarCode", nullable = false)
    private String barCode;
    private String accessno;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BookListId", referencedColumnName = "BookListId")
     @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})

    private LibraryBookListEntity parent;

    public LibraryBookListEntity getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(LibraryBookListEntity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public int getS_no() {
        return S_no;
    }

    public void setS_no(int S_no) {
        this.S_no = S_no;
    }

    public String getBarCode() {
        return barCode;
    }

    public void setBarCode(String barCode) {
        this.barCode = barCode;
    }

    public String getAccessno() {
        return accessno;
    }

    public void setAccessno(String accessno) {
        this.accessno = accessno;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean **existing** parent??

Comment: yes for the exciting parent i need to add one more child.

Comment: wht is this can u plz expline me.

Comment: Get out your English dictionary, and look up the words "exciting" and "existing".  Observe that they mean different things ...

Answer (score 0):

You formed new set . You have to set that to the parent object (that is  lb1). Then if u save lb1 changes in the child set will be saved. (Make sure you have given cascede save-update or all property in mapping for the set )

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("inside library model edit");
            mb = new LibraryBarCodeEntity();
            System.out.println("bar[i]" + bar[i]);
            System.out.println("bar[i]" + accission[i]);
            mb.setBarCode(bar[i]);
            mb.setAccessno(accission[i]);
            mb.setParent(lbl);
            para.add(new Phrase(new Chunk(BarcodeDao.genarateBarcode(bar[i], writer), 0, 0, true)));
            para.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));
            para.add(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));
           s.add(mb);

        }
         lbl.setChield(s);
         ses.saveOrUpdate(lbl);
        tx.commit();
```

Comment: why the cascade type is SAVE_UPDATE will not allow.

Comment: you can give save_update also . It will save or update inner set when parent set is saving or updating

Comment: Now I am getting exception like this Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`treamisdemo`.`librarybarcodetable`, CONSTRAINT `FKC205D3495D63121A` FOREIGN KEY (`BookListId`) REFERENCES `librarybooklisttable` (`BookListId`)).

Comment: Can u post Mapping file, Entity , DB structure in the question ? Then only this can be resolved

Comment: I think problem is in the following lines                           for (LibraryBarCodeEntity lbb : s1) {
            System.out.println("inside delte");
            ses.delete(lbb);    
        }       Just Comment the for loop and check

Comment: Now I am getting exception like this Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: I am not sure abt this . Give cascade all and try . .

Comment: Now that exception is not coming but my another child is not saving

Comment: I think instead of deleting existing set and adding new set you can make changes in existing set and update it. It will work and it is the right approach

Comment: while editing I will create new child for the exciting child's that new child will not saving for that parent.